# How to find all the vertices of graph that have the same status as a vertex $v$?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, group-theory

We sometimes say that in a graph $G$ two vertices $a$ and $b$  look the same. In layman's terms, this means that $a$ and $b$ are of same status. Precisely, there exists a auto-isomorphic mapping of $G$ mapping $a$ to $b$.

For example, in the graph below, $u$ and $v$ have the same status, and $x$ and $y$ have the same status.

[image]

I have two goals:

1. Given a vertex of a graph, find all the vertices  that have the same status as it.
2. To divide all vertices of the same status together.

For the first goal, my feeling is that the `GraphAutomorphismGroup` function can help.

```
g = Graph[{x <-> u, x <-> v, v <-> y, y <-> u, x <-> y}]
gr = GraphAutomorphismGroup[g]
(* output: PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 4}}], Cycles[{{2, 3}}]}]*)
```

From above output of *gr*, we can sense that some vertices are symmetrical, but the readability is a bit poor.

PS: The advantage of doing that is, for example, if we want to describe if the graph is planar (or whatever it is) if we remove one vertex. Just consider a representation of vertices of the same status.  (This saves time when the graph is highly symmetrical.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your **same status** means the element is in the same orbit in its automorphism group as *Group Theory*. And it means there is an element $g$ in its automorphism group such that the image of one point under $g$ is the other point

```
VertexList[g][[#]]&/@GroupOrbits[gr]
```

> {{x,y},{u,v}}